# Converting an odds ratio to a standardised mean difference, so that it can be used in a meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

[image: guidance for the conversion of an odds ratio to smd]

Where has the author got the blue 3 from, in line 2 of the code shown?

Comment: In the popular Meta package based on R language, there are two functions "smd2or" and "or2smd", which can realize conversion between standardized mean difference and odds ratio. https://rdrr.io/cran/meta/man/or2smd.html
https://rdrr.io/cran/meta/man/smd2or.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variance of a standard logistic is $\frac{\pi ^ 2}{3}$ so to convert from that scale onto a standard normal you perform the steps shown in the text from which you pasted the image. See for instance the article by Sue Chinn [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1097-0258(20001130)19:22%3C3127::AID-SIM784%3E3.0.CO;2-M/abstract) entitled "A simple method for converting an odds ratio to effect size for use in meta-analysis". If the text book or course from which you took the image does not explain that you maybe would benefit from finding a better one.

Comment: My next problem is converting an odds ratio (or underpinning data) into a d statistic? Any ideas?

Comment: Just run the same formula but in reverse.