# Converting Cohen's d to a Relative Risk for a model-based economic evaluation

Tags: meta-analysis, percentage, cohens-d, relative-risk

Hello researchers: my question is about the use of forest plot results for an economic model.

In a forest plot you could have the following results: 0.34 [0.22, 0.45], which would be the pooled estimate of the Cohen's d of multiple studies. What we want to know is; how can we use this information in a model-based economic evaluation? The pooled estimate is a cohen's d and in our model we have percentages. For example, we have e.g. 44% medication adherence in the control group and the other group has a higher percentage because of the cohen's d of 0.34. But how much higher?

Probably the sensible solution is converting the Cohen's d to a Relative Risk because with the RR we can calculate how much the results of our meta-analysis influences the percentage of people that adhere to their medication.

Would calculating the RR indeed be the best solution? If so, how can we calculate the RR from the Cohen's d?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315672/converting-an-odds-ratio-to-a-standardised-mean-difference-so-that-it-can-be-us/315737#315737 help?