# Generic inverse variance meta-analysis with metagen function, how to report results?

Tags: meta-analysis

I have recently performed a pairwise meta-analysis where I pooled the effect estimates and variances of different studies that either reported mean differences and odds ratio for the two arms using the generic inverse variance method **(metagen from metafor)**. Most of the original effect estimates were mean differences for which I computed standardized mean differences.

How do I report my final pooled estimate in my manuscript please?
In other words, as I pooled standardized treatment effect estimates and variances from both odds ratios and mean differences, will my final pooled estimate be a standaradized mean difference or odds ratio?   Just fyi, the value of the estimate I got is 0.08[-0.03;0.18]

Comment: How did you convert the SMD to OR, or OR to SMD?

Comment: For studies reporting OR, I calculated effect estimate for the OR as “log OR” and pooled it with the SMD from the other studies that reported a mean difference using metagen.

Comment: That does not answer the question I raised. Did you convert those log odds before using them in metagen (which is not part of metafor by the way).

Comment: No, I didnt..is there a way to do that?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315672/converting-an-odds-ratio-to-a-standardised-mean-difference-so-that-it-can-be-us/315737#315737