# Strange formulas for binary outcomes in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, binary-data, odds-ratio, risk-difference

I am reading the book: Shahjahan Khan. Meta-Analysis Methods for Health and Experimental Studies. Springer 2020. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-15-5032-4

On page 23, there are formulas for conversion of effect sizes for binary outcomes.

[image: Source: Shahjahan Khan. Meta-Analysis Methods for Health and Experimental Studies. Springer 2020.]

I am quite lost at this point. Where do all these formulas come from? Can anyone explain please?

Comment: See the answers here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315672/converting-an-odds-ratio-to-a-standardised-mean-difference-so-that-it-can-be-us/315737#315737

Comment: @mdewey Thank you.