Meta-analysis with effect sizes calculated from continuous and binary data
Can I compare effect sizes (ES) Cohen's g (from continuous outcome data) with effect size log odds (proportion outcome data) in a meta-analysis? Or can you only compare like for like, and why?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315672/converting-an-odds-ratio-to-a-standardised-mean-difference-so-that-it-can-be-us/315737#315737
